# It is necessary to keep the lib folder of the JRE package?

Tags: windows, internet, browser, java, jre

I would like to know whether after installed the Java Runtimes (JRE) on Windows, it is necessary for the webbrowser to keep the "lib" folder stored at: `C:\Program Files\Java\jre***\lib`, or I can safely remove it after installation?...since this folders it seems to contain just source-code files if I'm not wrong.

Comment: You are wrong. [jar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_(file_format)) files are **not** source files. The JRE will not work if they are deleted.

Comment: `lib` folder contains JAR packages contain standard class libraries required to run Java VM & `.properties` configuration files, so **don't delete them** - deleting may cause unexpected "missing packages" error.